# Error in perl with Cassandra

Tags: perl, caching, asynchronous, cassandra, synchronous

I am writing my Cassandra cache class in Perl 5.18.2 with [`Net::Async::CassandraCQL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Async::CassandraCQL).

This is my just test example:

```
# in first subroutine
$self->_loop( new IO::Async::Loop );
$self->_cacheIO(new Net::Async::CassandraCQL(
host                => $self->server->{ ip },
service             => $self->server->{ port },
keyspace            => $self->_keyspace,
default_consistency => CONSISTENCY_QUORUM,));
$self->_loop()->add( $self->_cacheIO );
$self->_cacheIO()->connect->get;

# in second subroutine
$self->_cacheIO()->query( "INSERT INTO cacheTable (key, value) VALUES ('keeeey1', 'you will pay');" )->get();
```

And i am getting this error on insert query:

```
IO::Async::Future=HASH(0x2e8a4b8) IO::Async::Future=HASH(0x2e8a4b8) lost a sequence Future at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/Async/CassandraCQL/Connection.pm line 231.
```

I already read this https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=97260
so it could be bug. But i think that maybe it could be overcome with [`IO::Async::Notifier`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Notifier) adopt_future method. Do you have any experience with notifier and future. Any examples? Any ideas for the error and how to solve it.

Maybe it will be better to ask how to do this synchronous?

```
PERL_FUTURE_DEBUG=1 perl ./test.pl
    (in cleanup) ERROR CODE #5
IO::Async::Future=HASH(0x5607cd8) was constructed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/Async/CassandraCQL/Connection.pm line 595 and was lost near /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Future.pm line 346 before it was ready.
IO::Async::Future=HASH(0x560f1a0) (constructed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/IO/Async/Loop.pm line 553) lost a sequence Future at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/Async/CassandraCQL/Connection.pm line 231.
    (in cleanup)
IO::Async::Future=HASH(0x56030b8) was constructed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/Async/CassandraCQL/Connection.pm line 504 and was lost near /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Carp.pm line 168 before it was ready.
```

Its very strange, when i get this error and select the database i can see that inserted data are in table...

Update: ist not error but warning.

Answer (score 2):

This was reported as a bug some time ago. It has since been fixed; see

https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=97260